# The error "there is no line to end here" when using \\~\\ or \newline

Tags: spacing, errors, line-spacing

When I want to have a space between lines I use `\\~\\` or `\newline`

For example

```
    Hello this is an example

    \\~\\

   Goodbye
```

I get the error there is no line to end here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to skip a line, use

```
First line

\medskip

last line
```

A larger space is obtained with `\bigskip`

Comment: I thought `\medskip` was defined by the document class, is it always guaranteed (assuming the user hasn't redefined it) to be the equivalent of skipping a line?

Comment: @Au101 Not strictly “skipping a line”, but it leaves a visible amount of white space. It's not necessary (and I'd not recommend it) to have a full “blank line”.

Answer (score 1):

You should not skip lines in this manner, you're better off using `\vspace`.

however, to answer your question, what you have there actually is

```
First line

\newline
~
\newline

last line
```

The first newline does not have a line to end.
so it should simply be

```
First line

~\\

last line
```

Comment: I think the mention of `\vspace` should come right at the start. The line skipping is not recomendable at all.

Comment: I agree, edited accordingly

Comment: @eladden  \vspace doesnt really do anything to my code.

Comment: @Aljabra the way to use it is `\vspace{sizeofskip}` check out this link https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces
you can also use `\medskip`

Comment: This answer is wrong

Comment: while that avoids the error message the markup `~\\ ` is still completely wrong and  would for example produce something that looks like vertical space but is in fact a paragraph with no text that is not dropped at a page break, and as always if you end a paragraph with `\\ ` you will get underfull; box 10000 warnings.

Comment: And the recommendations in the sharelatex page are wrong as well