# Getting error: "There is no line here to end" when trying to do a line break between two paragraphs

Tags: errors, line-breaking

I try to add additional space between two paragraphs but I'm getting the error:"There is no line here to end". I want to have exact two line breaks between each paragraph.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}

\vspace*{-2.54cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{16}{0}\selectfont \textbf{some text}
\end{center}

\newline
\newline

\begin{center}
\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont some other text
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not "tweak" the layout that way. LaTeX is not *word*...

Comment: Also related: [The error “there is no line to end here” when using \\~\\ or \newline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320874/the-error-there-is-no-line-to-end-here-when-using-or-newline)

Answer (score 1):

You might force `\newline` by adding `\leavevmode` before:
`\leavevmode\newline`. (If you really want to do this)

Comment: \leavevmode\newline worked out perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it works for you, you should accept the answer by clicking on the tick on the left. Thanks :)

Comment: @gamma doing this stops latex error checking so removes the error message but the error is still there and the layout will still be bad.